# iOS - pause AVSpeech while reading a specific word

Tags: ios, objective-c, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm working on an app that reads the text in a `UITextField` using `AVSpeech` and I'm trying to pause reading when it reads a specific word, for example its reading this `This is awesome.` and I want it to pause reading for 2 seconds when it reads `is` and then complete reading. Here is my code to read the string.

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:@"This is awesome"];
utterance.rate = 0.15;
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-us"];
[synth speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Separate your utterance string on occurrences of "is" and put the components in an array. Read each string in the array in order with a `sleep(2)` in between. Keep in mind that sleeping on the main thread will disable your UI interactions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(void)pauseSpeechReading
{
    if([synthesize isSpeaking]) {
        NSLog(@"Reading paused");
        [synthesize pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
        AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@""];
        [synthesize speakUtterance:utterance];
        [synthesize pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
    }
}
-(void)resumeSpeechReading
{
     NSLog(@"Reading resumed");
    [synthesize continueSpeaking];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is good article on NSHipster about TTS for iOS - http://nshipster.com/avspeechsynthesizer/

Please read **Delegate** section of article - you find a way to display currently speaked out word. Then just use **synthesize pauseSpeakingAtBoundary** to pause for 2 seconds then resume TTS.

Complete sample project is on GitHub: https://github.com/mattt/AVSpeechSynthesizer-Example. You can find some other useful technics for working with TTS.

Answer (score 0):

Split into two utterances and set the second with .preUtteranceDelay = 2.0